# Error AADSTS50034 when attempting to change password for local Azure AD B2C users with a username from an external domain

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am working on Azure AD B2C for my Angular 6 front-end App and consuming Microsoft Graph API in order to change the singed-in user's password. I am getting the `access_token` using the Authorization Code flow.

It works fine when the user has a username like `xyz@myb2cname.onmicrosoft.com`, I get an `access_token` and then call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/changePassword`.

But when I try to do the same for users with a username like `xyz@gmail.com` or `abc@hotmail.com`, I get an error when acquiring the `access_token from`  Authorization Code flow (`grant_type=password`). **Note: These users are "local" accounts in my AAD B2C tenant**

Following is the error message I get:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50034: To sign into this application the account must be 
                          added to the myb2cname.onmicrosoft.com directory.
                          Trace ID: 8fcae061-5088-4393-9e5b-d0a83d1d0a00
                          Correlation ID: 0dc6c906-c54b-4cd8-ae8b-46f3f6118e40
                          Timestamp: 2018-08-01 06:16:55Z",
    "error_codes": [
        50034
    ],
    "timestamp": "2018-08-01 06:16:55Z",
    "trace_id": "8fcae061-5088-4393-9e5b-d0a83d1d0a00",
    "correlation_id": "0dc6c906-c54b-4cd8-ae8b-46f3f6118e40"
}
```

How can I call `changePassword` for users who are signed in using the email identity provider (SignIn-SignUp Policy) when their username looks like `xyz@gmail.com` or `abc@hotmail.com instead` of `xyz@myb2cname.onmicrosoft.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an external user signs into your AAD, it does not create a traditional user with a traditional password, it creates a "guest" user. The actual user remains in the originating AAD tenant, your AAD tenant only stores a placeholder for that user.

You cannot change a guest user's password since your AAD doesn't actually have a password assigned to that user. Your AAD holds the authorization (what the user has access to) but relies on the user's AAD for authentication (the user is who they claim to be).

Comment: So what I am assuming by your answer is that, if user signs up into my B2C app from login/signup page using any identity providers whether its Microsoft, Google, Facebook or Email signup(Local Account) I can't change their password using microsft graph changePassword endpoint? 
I think I misunderstood Email signup(Local Account), in the end it is also an Identity Provider like the others and user who created their accounts using Email Signup with arbitrary email address (for example bob@gmail.com) are still not same as work or school account.

Comment: Accounts can be either local, social, or a combination of the two. You need to make sure that this is set up properly if you wish to use the combination. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-social-migration for a more details.

Answer (score 1):

It is the expected behavior. You need to understand AD clearly before implementing it.

In Azure AD, to authenticate a user against a Directory, the user should be a part the Active Directory. The users, who are not a part of the Active Directory will not be authenticated. The token gets generated only when the user is authenticated.

Trying to generate a token for a user who is not a part of the Active Directory is similar to logging into Azure Portal with a invalid user account.

Comment: I have already mentioned in question above, that users are signed up into my application. When i go to  my AD B2C registered app i can see those users in users listing. That means they are part of my directory, Even if they signed up with xyz@gmail.com or any other external email domain provider **instead of**  xxx@myB2Cname.onmicrosoft.com.

Comment: Did you created a password reset policy?

Comment: I did, I guess they are used for resetting password from login page! That is working fine though. What i want is, User can change password from the app after they login using Microsoft graph changePassword, It works for my B2C users with xxx@myB2Cname.onmicrosoft.com username. But not for users with xyz@gmail or xyz@hotmail.com.

Comment: I think you need to modify the External collaboration settings to make the guest users leverage Graph APIs.

Comment: Can you please provide any link to Microsoft updated document on this, So i can go through it and implement it(modify settings). Thanks.

Comment: I can't find a link from Microsoft. The settings is available in Active Directory => Users=> User Settings => External users

Comment: I had this doubt before, and went to this settings page in my Azure AD B2C, But whenever i get into this page i see this error message **Sorry! You do not have access to this page**. I think i need to get access to this, and try changing settings here and that should work, I will do it and revert as soon as possible, thank you very much for guiding.

Comment: You should be a global admin of the Directory to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change passwords for local account users using the Microsoft Graph API because, currently, an Azure AD B2C application can't be registered with the Microsoft Application Registration Portal and, therefore, it can't be used with the Microsoft Graph API.

You should change passwords for local account users using [a custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-password-change-custom).

This means the Azure AD B2C application doesn't have to collect either the current or new passwords for users.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same situation where I was able to create and update the user in AZURE AD-B2C
but not able to delete or reset the password.
Because Currently, the Read and write directory data permission does NOT include the ability to delete users or update user passwords

[Configure delete or update password permissions for your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#configure-delete-permissions-for-your-application)

To archive this I had to follow the above link and it worked like a charm.