# How to update password for guest users in azure ad using graph API.? Python

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, change-password

I have added few guest users and members in azure active directory. Members are those for which the username I have created for ex `name@tenantname.info`. Guest users are like the one which are from lets say google, so I have added them as `name@google.com`.

Now I have code which updates the password of the members. Below is the code:

```
# Getting token
r = requests.post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + config_data['TENANT'] + "/oauth2/token",
      data={"grant_type": "client_credentials",
            "client_secret": config_data['CLIENT_SECRET'],
            "client_id": config_data['CLIENT_ID'],
            "resource": config_data['RESOURCE']})
            
ret_body = r.json()
token = ret_body['access_token']

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

user_data = {
    "accountEnabled": True,
    "userPrincipalName": "name@tenantname.info",
    "passwordProfile": {
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": False,
        "password": "<password>"
    }
}

jdata = json.dumps(user_data)

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('graph.microsoft.com')
conn.request("PATCH", "/v1.0/users/name@tenantname.info", jdata, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
```

Above code works perfectly fine and I am able to update password for the members but it gives below error if I want to update password for guest users:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-07-22T04:25:18",
            "request-id": "a6edf8e1-2256-4076-acc8-440607fa6119"
        },
        "message": "Resource 'name@google.com' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what additional parameters I have to use in order to update password for guest users. Please help. Thanks

Screenshot of the app permission:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Screenshot of jwt.ms

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot use `name@tenantname.info` as the request parameter, you should use `Object ID` as the request parameter(for guest users, object id is needed. Ordinary member users can use account names).

```
 PATCH  /v1.0/users/<your guest user Object id>
```

After my test, I found that using the correct request parameters to modify the guest user’s password, although there will be a correct response, but in fact, the password of the guest user still has not been modified. Therefore, in summary, you cannot change the guest user’s password. Because your AAD does not actually assign a password for this user.

A similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51627004/error-aadsts50034-when-attempting-to-change-password-for-local-azure-ad-b2c-user?rq=1) for your reference.

Comment: What is a guest user object id and from where can I get it.?

Comment: @SAndrew   You only need to request the `/v1.0/users` api, and you will get all user information. There will be an `id` field, which is the `object id`.

Comment: Do we need any special permission to modify guest users password because I got error `"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."`

Comment: @SAndrew Yes,when updating the passwordProfile property, the following permission is required: Directory.AccessAsUser.All.

Comment: I am able to update the password of members which means that I have all the permissions set correctly. Do we need any other permission for guest user specially.?

Comment: @SAndrew  I need you to provide two screenshots: 1. Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token to provide screenshots, 2. Go to Azure ad API permissions to provide screenshots.

Comment: Sorry for being late but I have updated the question

Comment: @SAndrew   According to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http, when updating the passwordProfile attribute, the Directory.AccessAsUser.All permission must be required, but this permission is a delegated permission, so it is recommended that you use the authorization code flow. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow.

Comment: Thank you I will follow the link but as you mentioned that in case of guest user, its not possible to update passwords. Does following the link, will I be able to update the passwords of the guest users as well.?

Comment: This can only solve the problem of insufficient permissions. For changing the password of the guest user, as I said in the answer, this is not possible. Although there will be a correct response when you request the API to change the password, but in fact The password has not been changed.